# Querying against a simple array stored as json

Tags: postgresql-json

How do I check a row for the existence of an integer which are stored in a json column like so
    [3, 7, 11, 9]
Because there are no structured json objects having names in that column I cannot use the syntax **where obj->>'something' = 3**. There is just no 'something'.

Comment: why not obtain a string representation of the row, like displaying the elements separated by commas as "3, 7, 11, 9", and then searching the string for a given element ? like myString.indexOf("7") ?

Comment: Ok - this will work. But this proceeding cannot make use of indexes (available in postgres 9.4). I would rather have a way to use indexes in the future.

Comment: what with what I said below, spliting the string in an array, and searching for a given array element, will not do ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do obtain a string representation of the row, like displaying the elements separated by commas as "3, 7, 11, 9", and then searching the string for a given element, using indexOf method, like myString.indexOf("7"). You could also split this string by commas, obtaining an array of the elements. Then you could use Array.indexOf to check whether the element exists in the array.

Follows an example:

```js
var obj = [3, 7, 11, 9]
var strRepresentation = obj.toString();
var array = strRepresentation.split(',');

function elementExists(e)
{
   return e + " exists in the array? " + (array.indexOf(e.toString()) != -1).toString();
}

alert(elementExists(7)); //returns true
alert(elementExists(13)); //returns false
```